# C# Multiple Interface Inheritance does not allow public access modifier with same name

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance, encapsulation, access-modifiers

So this has me perplexed.
Suppose two interfaces.

```
public interface a
{
    void foo();
}

public interface b
{
    void foo();
}
```

Both of those interfaces have a function foo, I have a class that provides explicit implementation:

```
public class alpha : a, b
{
    // why can't I put an access modifier here?
    // How would you be able to hide this from a derived class
    void a.foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }

   void b.foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }
}
```

And a Class that is derived from alpha

```
public class beta : alpha
{
}
```

How do you make foo private or protected since alpha doesn't allow access modifiers on explicit imlementation, what can stop someone from calling:

```
var be = new beta();
(be as b).foo();
```

**EDIT**

How come when I don't explicitly provide implementation I can provide an access modifier?

```
public class alpha : a, b
{
   //why this compile? 
   public void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("both");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't.  This is how Explicit Interface implementations work.  Casting the object to that specific Explicit Interface will expose the members.  If you don't want it to be exposed, don't guarantee it in your interface.

Comment: There's no way to hide the implementation, but ... You could implement `foo` of `b` explicitely on `beta` too, throwing an exception ...

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - please tell us why you want to hide `foo` on `beta`...

Comment: Note that in "explicitly provide implementation I *can* provide an access modifier" - the "can" part is not exactly correct - since interface implementation has to be either `public` or explicit the only choice you have for implicit implementation is "*must* specify `public`" rather than "*can* provide modifier".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since interface `a` is public, any class that implements `a` must make the methods of `a` publicly accessible, either implicitly (through public methods) or explicitly.  Explicit implementations are "sort-of" private since they can only be accessed through the interface.

In short, there is *no way* to completely "hide" `foo` - your class implements both `a` and `b` so those methods *must* me made accessible through some means.

This would be true even if you only had *one* interface - having multiple interfaces with a method name collision just forces you to make the implementations explicit.  If you had one interface, `foo` would either have to be `public` or explicit.

Comment: How come when I don't explicitly provide implementation I can provide an access modifier?

Comment: You can provide an access modifier, but it has to be `public`.  If the interface is `public` the implicit implementation has to be `public`.  You can't make `foo` anything other than `public` or you violate the interface contract.

Comment: Oh, Its just wierd that you can't provide public on explicit implementation but you can only provide public on implicit implementation

Comment: @johnny5 the rules of language sometimes cause such strange issues. Note that is this particular case implementation can come from base class and interface from child - so if parent class *did not* want to expose method it would make it private/protected and as result derived class need to be prevented from exposing such method when interface on derived class forces it to be public.

Comment: @johnny5 It your case, yes, because the _interface_ is public.  If the interface was `internal` the method could be `internal` or `public`. The implementation can't be _less accessible_ than the interface.

Answer (score 6):

> what can stop someone from calling

Nothing, that's the whole point!

`beta` is a `b` and thus you can treat it as a `b`. If you choose to cast it to `b` and call the explicit `foo` implementation you'll get `b` implementation.

Comment: How come when I don't explicitly provide implementation I can provide an access modifier?

Comment: A choice of 1 - `public`.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in other answers theses are rules of the language and had to be followed.

Sample showing why explicitly specifying `public` on interface implementation is required:

```
class Base
{
   protected void Foo() { } 
}

public interface IFoo
{
   void Foo();
}
```

Class `Base` explicitly made choice to not expose method `Foo` to users of the class (except derived, could be `private` too).

Now if another class wants to derive from `Base` and implement `IFoo` at the same time. If language would allow to just pick implementations irrespective of access modifiers it would mean that `Base.Foo` is now exposed by derived to every caller:

```
class Derived : Base, IFoo 
{
    // hypothetical compiler allows to pick any matching `void Foo` 
    // including inherited `protected void Base.Foo()`
}
```

This would be clearly against intent of `Base` class to hide `Foo` method - so language have to require `Foo` to be `public` to be considered as part of interface.

As result you end up with "optional" access modifier on interface implementation where you have exactly one option - must specify `public`.

Note that `Derived` has couple options to deal with `Foo` - explicit implementation and shadowing with `new`:

```
class Derived : Base, IFoo
{
   new public void Foo() {}
}
```